# kernel in c inline assembly

Tags: x86, kernel, nasm, bootloader, real-mode

Hi i have once again a problem i try to write a kernel with the GNU assembly language but i have some trouble.
My kernel file `versuch.c` look like that:

```
 void kprintf( char hello[])
   {
   /*char* video=(char*)0xb8000;
 for(int i=0;hello[i]!='\0';i++)
{
    video[i*2]=hello[i];

    video[i*2+1]=0x06;

}*/
    asm("mov %0,%%si"::""(hello));
    //asm("mov 'a',%al;");
    asm("call Schreibe;"    
        "Schreibe:;"
        "lodsb;"
        "cmp $0x00,%al;"
        "je Schreibeende;"
        "mov $0x0e,%ah;"
        "mov $0x00,%bh;"
        "int $0x10;"
        "jmp Schreibe;"
        "Schreibeende:;"
        "ret");

}

void main()
{
    asm("jmp    0x10000");
    char hello[]="hallo";
    kprintf(hello);
    asm(".rept 512;"
        " hlt ;"
        ".endr");
}`
```

and my bootloader `bootloader.asm`:

```
org 0x7c00
bits    16



    section .text

xor ax,ax
mov ss,ax
xor sp,sp

;xor ax,ax
;mov es,ax 
;mov ds,ax


mov [bootdrive],dl


mov bh,0
mov bp,zeichen

mov ah,13h
mov bl,06h
mov al,1
mov cx,6
mov dh,010h
mov dl,01h

int 10h

load:
mov dl,[bootdrive]
xor ah,ah
int 13h
jc load

load2:
mov ax,0x1000
mov es,ax
xor bx,bx

mov ah,2
mov al,1
mov cx,2
xor dh,dh

mov dl,[bootdrive]
int 13h
jc load2


mov ax,0
mov es,ax

mov bh,0
mov bp,zeichen3

mov ah,13h
mov bl,06h
mov al,1
mov cx,13
mov dh,010h
mov dl,01h

int 10h

mov ax,0x1000
mov es,ax
mov ds,ax
jmp 0x1000:0x000

zeichen db  'hello2'
zeichen3 db 'soweit so gut'
bootdrive db 0
times   510 - ($-$$)    hlt
dw  0xaa55
```

when i use the commands:
`gcc -c versuch.c`
`objcopy -O binary versuch.o versuch.bin`
`cat bootloader.bin versuch.bin>myOS.bin`
`qemu-system-i386 myOS.bin`
you can see that it runs through the bootloader to the end printing out "soweit so gut" but it doesnt display the versuch.c(kernel) text "hallo".
Maybe someone knows what i did wrong here!

The thing is that the kernel code i had before which was just slightly changed to the code above at least printed out a character after "soweit so gut" which shows that the kernel code was somehow executed and

```
mov $0xe,%ah
mov $0x0,%bh
int $0x10
```

was run.
But when i look at the hexcode from myOS.bin now via `objdump -Mi8086 -mi386 -bbinary -D myOS.bin` i get:

```
 28:    b8 00 10 8e c0          mov    $0xc08e1000,%eax
  2d:   31 db                   xor    %ebx,%ebx
  2f:   b4 02                   mov    $0x2,%ah
  31:   b0 01                   mov    $0x1,%al
  33:   b9 02 00 30 f6          mov    $0xf6300002,%ecx
  38:   8a 16                   mov    (%esi),%dl
  3a:   76 7c                   jbe    0xb8
  3c:   cd 13                   int    $0x13
```

which is the `mov ah,0x1000` `xor bx,bx` disk reading part of the bootloader
and

```
60: e9 9d 83 68 65          jmp    0x65688402
```

which is the `jmp 0x10000` part
and

```
 27d:   b4 0e                   mov    $0xe,%ah
 27f:   b7 00                   mov    $0x0,%bh
 281:   cd 10                   int    $0x10
```

which is the writing part, so somehow it must overjump the writing part but it is in the myOS.bin file. And as  i said when my code was just slightly different with the string, it did put out something!
Do you have any advice what i could have changed?

i recently changed my kernel code versuch.c while the command and the bootloader code remains the same.

kernel code(versuch.c):

```
void kprintf()
{
    char* video=(char*)0xb8000;
    for(int i=0;video[i]!=0;i++)
    {
        video[i*2]=0x00;
        video[i*2+1]=0x06;
    }
}
void main()
{
    asm("jmp    0x10000");
    asm("mov    $0x1000,%eax;"
        "mov    %eax,%es;"
        "mov    %eax,%ds");
    asm("mov    $0x0e,%ah;"
        "mov    $0x00,%bh;"
        "mov    'Q',%al;"
        "int $0x10");
    asm(".rept 512;"
        " hlt ;"
        ".endr");
}
```

now it seems to switch to the video mode showing a blinking cursor but it doesnt print out 'Q'.

i finally got to print a letter with the following kernel code:
versuch.c:

```
void kprintf()
{
    char* video=(char*)0xb8000;
    for(int i=0;video[i]!=0;i++)
    {
        video[i*2]=0x00;
        video[i*2+1]=0x06;
    }
}
void main()
{
    asm("jmp    0x10000");
    asm("mov    $0x1000,%eax;"
        "mov    %eax,%es;"
        "mov    %eax,%ds");
    asm("mov $0x0e,%ah");
    asm("mov $0x00,%bh");
    asm("mov %0,%%al":: "" ('T'));
    asm("int $0x10");
    asm(".rept 512;"
        " hlt ;"
        ".endr");
}
```

but when i add another function its not working again that really strange.

My new kernel code looks like this:

```
asm("jmp main");



void main()
{
    char* video=(char*)0xb000;
    for(int i=0;video[i]!=0;i++)
        video[i]=0x07;
    asm("mov    $0x1000,%eax;"
        "mov    %eax,%es;"
        "mov    %eax,%ds");
    char string[]="hall0";
    //kprintf(string);
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
    {

    asm("mov $0x0e,%ah");
    asm("mov $0x00,%bh");
    asm("mov %0,%%al":: "" ('a'));
    asm("int $0x10");
    }

    asm(".rept 512;"
        " hlt ;"
        ".endr");
}
```

i used the following commands:
`gcc kernel.c -m16 -c kernel.o -nostdlib -ffreestanding`
`ld -melf_i386 kernel.o -o versuch.elf`
and i am using Mint Linux 64 bit machine and i get the error message:
`no eh_frame_hdr_table will be created`

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130996/discussion-on-question-by-albert-kernel-in-c-inline-assembly).

Answer (score 2):

What C compiler do you use?

A 32-bit or even a 64-bit compiler?

(Because you simply use `gcc` and not something like `x86-16bit-gcc` I think you use a 32-bit or 64-bit compiler.)

This won't work - you'll have to switch to **protected mode** to be able to run 32-bit code. Running 64-bit code is even more difficult.

Even when you use "only" inline assembly the compiler itself will add some instructions - and they are 32-bit or 64-bit instructions!

Or do you really use a 16-bit compiler?

In this case you'll have to be very careful: Which memory model do you use and what side effects do this have?

Example: Using a "near" memory model the line:

```
video=(char*)0xb8000;
```

... will truncate the address 0xb8000 to a 16-bit value (0x8000).

Using a "far" memory model however 0xb8000 is typically seen as 0x000b:0x8000 (which is equal to the linear address 0x13000) by **most** compilers. For these compilers the value 0xb8000000 has to be used to access 0xb800:0x0000 (linear address 0xB8000).

Using `objcopy` the following line definitely won't work:

```
kprintf(hello);
```

The reason is that the compiler will internally do something like this:

```
kprintf((char *)0x12345);
```

0x12345 is the address where the string "hello" is stored. However this address is not known, yet, when the program is compiled.

For this reason the object file contains some information about the fact that the number 0x12345 must be replaced by the real address of the string later. The **linker** will do this when you link a program. Using `objcopy` however this information is simply lost and the number remains 0x12345.

By the way:

Your program contains the line:

```
jmp 0x1000:0x000
```

Why do you think that this is the location of `main`?

Comment: it does know display some wierd character instead of "hallo" its a 65 bit compiler

Comment: You may try to disassemble your code to see what really is done: `objdump -Mi8086 -mi386 -bbinary -D versuch.bin`. Then you can see how the code generated by the 64-bit compiler really looks like...

Comment: Thanks for the Help i will try this

Comment: i remember that this code printed something after "soweit so gut" when the code was slightly different, that shows that at least the kernel code was executed somehow

Comment: i wish i knew what i had different then it must have been just a small change

Comment: the reason why i think that that the main location is at `0x1000:0x000` is because i mad i disk read to this location

Comment: @albert : The disk read just reads the data that was saved to the sector, it doesn't know anything about what is in it. That is why it is up to you to make the first instructions in the _C_ files appear as the very first code.

Comment: But the writing  Code of the Kernel is in the myOS.bin file i think the it is just overjumped

Comment: do you know the location of the main entry?

Comment: also it did print out something in white letters after the "soweit so gut" when i had the `jmp 0x1000:0x000` in it, so it must be right.

Comment: strangely it seems that it all comes down to the last `jmp` command in the bootloader which doesnt fit with the before almost working code

Comment: but now according to the hexcode that i get with the command you adviced me `jmp 0x10000` translates to `jmp 0x65688402` so that it overjumps the printing part and `jmp 0x1000:0x000` translates to `ljmp $0x6568,$0x10000000` which could be the same